# TelosB mote and TinyOS

Tags: ubuntu, make

[image]

I am trying to Blink LED on TelosB mote. I have installed TinyOS but  I am having an issue with the `make` command. Could anybody be able to help?

Comment: It looks you don't have permission to create the build/ directory. As a quick workaround try with `sudo make`

Comment: Better workaround: `sudo chown -R youruser:yourgroup .`, and use sudo after that only to install.

Comment: @Mat why not post that as an answer? Please don't answer questions in comments.

Comment: @Thushi why not post that as an answer? Please don't answer questions in comments.

Comment: @terdon: Yeah, I can do that but it was just a workaround that might solve the OP's problem. And that is not the exact solution for that problem and for that we need to extract some more information from OP and we can conclude the problem and finalize the solution. That is the reason I didn't posted it as an answer :)